# Start Docker Image in AKS

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I have multiple batch jobs which have different runtime requirments, and I would like to create one (or few) exe files and package them in a docker image, and when I need to execute the jobs, I would spin the instance of apropriate size and let it do the work.

Azure-Functions and Azure container instances are almost perfect solution BUT they are both limited to 16 GB RAM, and I need more (256+ and more cores) . So what I am trying to achive is the method  [CreateContainerGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/containerinstance#:%7E:text=private%20static%20void%20CreateContainerGroup) but  beeing able to spin a larger node, so my guess is to run it in AKS, if so can it be done through c#?
or is there a better way to do it in Azure?

Edit: and applications require .net framework 4.8 so it must be windows docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Container Instances are limited to 16 GB RAM indeed. However you might have a look at [GPU instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-gpu), which allow up to 4 GPUs / 24 CPUs / 448 GB memory with max V100 SKU - depending on your case it might work for you.

If you would rather go with AKS using C#, then - assuming you have a cluster already set up - you need to look not for AKS client, but Kubernetes client instead. There are a few to pick from - an [official](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp) one and a few [community maintained](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/#community-maintained-client-libraries). [Here](https://github.com/masroorhasan/Kubernetes.DotNet#create-a-pod-in-namespace) is a concrete example of how to create a pod using one of them.